# Why does safari consider inline elements with no whitespace as a very wide single element?

Tags: html, css, layout, safari, webkit

**Update:** I've just updated to Safari Version 9.0 (10601.1.56.2), and the issue is resolved there.

---

Can someone explain (since keywords I used in google had too many results) how and why Safari specifically seems to consider inline elements without text or whitespace to be one wide element? And is there a fix other than always adding a whitespace/line-break between elements.

To demonstrate, view the following code snippet on Safari vs. Chrome. In Chrome the kittens line up one under the other. In Safari, the top container show two kittens horizontally, while the bottom container which has just one whitespace before the span element shows the kittens vertically lined up.

```css
.container {
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"><span></span>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"> <span></span>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot to show how Safari renders the code:
[image: how safari displays the above code]

Tested on: OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, Mac Pro (Mid 2010), Safari Version 8.0.5 (10600.5.17).
Same issue was found on Safari on the iOS devices as well, I've only tested on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 plus.

Comment: *"In Chrome the kittens line up one under the other."*  ~ I think you might misunderstand what "inline" means.   It does not mean lined up on top of each other.  "inline" means all in a line next to each other.  When there is not enough space, the following item simply wraps to the next line... like words in a sentence.

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of that, however what I'm pointing out is that even though the width is limited and therefore the elements should be wrapped to the next line, in the first container they don't do that on safari (desktop as well as on ios).

Comment: Like words in a sentence... without a space in between, they overflow the container instead of wrap.

Comment: What is your question?  Why Safari is different?  Every browser is slightly different in the way it interprets the standards.  Sometimes, they don't follow the standards at all.

Comment: Exactly, but why is that happening only in Safari, and also, it doesn't seem to be consistent to all inline elements, since three `<img>` tags without space between doesn't show that effect, but only when adjacent to a text tag, like `<span>`, `<a>` etc. does this happen.
Question is what's in the standard that Safari conforms to that causes this?

Comment: **Every browser is slightly different in the way it interprets the standards. Sometimes, they don't follow the standards at all.**  I don't know what else to tell you.  Otherwise, you can file a bug report/complaint with Apple.

Comment: I can't tell you the standard when I don't even know if you're following HTML 5 or 4.  See:  http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/ and/or http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/

Comment: I'm hoping for an explanation, or someone familiar with the quirks of safari. For argument's sake it's `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: This is more of a CSS issue than an HTML issue, since whitespace processing in layout is handled by CSS rather than HTML. Unfortunately, [CSS doesn't have much to say about this either](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model).

Comment: Which Safari version/OS are you referring to ? (*works fine in Win 7, Safari 5.0.5*)

Comment: Tested on: OSX Yosemite 10.10.3, Mac Pro (Mid 2010), Safari Version 8.0.5 (10600.5.17). Same issue was found on Safari on the iOS devices as well, I've only tested on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 plus.
(I added this info to the post)